# Php and css echo bordered text

Tags: php

I am using php and I want to echo a "Hello, world!" text. But I'd like that to be inside a border. I see borders are supported by css (http://www.w3schools.com/website/web_spa_css.asp but I don't know how to combine them both to form the result I want. Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: You need to apply the style to a specific element, and echo the entire element in PHP. For instance, if you apply the border property to a `div` with the class `border`, then you can simply use `echo '<div class="border">Hello, World!</div>`, as long as the CSS is linked to your document (either with a `<link>` tag, or in a `<style>`-tag. (A shorter way can be using the style-attribute within the bordered element [whichever that would be], but if you're going to use the border several times on your website, I wouldn't recommend that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you . try this then after you play with it to help you achieve the best results

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#getborder h2{
border:1px solid #444444;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="getborder">
<?php echo "<h2>Hello world!</h2>";?>
</div>
<html>
</body>
```